# Accessing variables inside a Javascript promise chain

Tags: javascript, methods, promise, httpresponse, chain

I am using a chained promise in JavaScript (I think). There is a then() function in the chain. I want to access the variable inside the promise, or somehow return the variable via my HTTP response object.

```
var getTitle = function(response)
{
    console.log("Starting getTitle. response: " + response); //this works

    var horseman = new Horseman();           // object for headless browser

    horseman
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0")
        .open('http://www.google.com/ncr')
        .type('input[name="q"]', 'github')
        .click("button:contains('Google Search')")  
        .keyboardEvent("keypress",16777221) // press Enter
        .waitForSelector("div.g")        
        .title()            // gets the title of the page
        .then(function(t) {
            console.log("title: " + t);     // this works
        })
        .close();

    console.log("title outside: " + t);     // this gives 'undefined'

    return t;          // returns 'undefined'
}
```

How can I extract the 't' variable? I also tried passing 'response' into the function like

```
.then(function(t, response) {
```

But when I log 'response', it is undefined. If I could pass in the response object somehow, that would also work.

If I do

```
var test = horseman...
```

test becomes a promise object, but it doesn't contain the t variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, You say that the title is rightly available inside the .then function. Are you trying to return that to the caller of the function?

Comment: Yes. Well, the goal is to have `response` and `t` accessible in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

This did it:

```
var getTitle = function(response)
{
    console.log("Starting getTitle. response: " + response); //this works

    var horseman = new Horseman();           // object for headless browser

    var xyz = horseman
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0")
        .open('http://www.google.com/ncr')
        .type('input[name="q"]', 'github')
        .click("button:contains('Google Search')")  
        .keyboardEvent("keypress",16777221) // press Enter
        .waitForSelector("div.g")        
        .title()            // gets the title of the page
        .finally(function (t) {
            horseman.close();
            return t;
        });

    return xyz;         
}
```

In the calling function:

```
var abc = getTitle(response);
abc.then(function(abc) {
    console.log("abc: " + abc);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(abc);
```

It didn't work if I put any more lines of code inside the finally block; I don't know why. I can probably remove the `response` parameter; need to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning from within a .finally().

```
    .finally(function(t){
        return t;
    });
```

Comment: finally does not receive parameters

Answer (score 0):

You cann't `return t` from function `getTitle`, but you have 2 options here.

1.To do all you need with `t` inside callback function in `then`, or pass callback function as parameter

```
var getTitle = function(response, callback) {
...
.then(function(t) {
    callback(t);
});
```

2.To return promise from `getTitle` and use `then` to handle response.

```
return horseman;
...
var t = getTitle(response);
t.then(function(t){/* handle t */});
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the `response` object into callback()?

Comment: You pass callback function as parameter to getTitle function, inside of it you can pass t and response to it if you need. callback(t, response).