# Empty row on MongoDB data insertion using express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I want to add data to my MongoDB collection. I'm getting this data via a local Flask API. I'm GETting the data on my React Frontend and it's displaying fine. I'm not sure why I can't do the same thing on my express nodejs backend. I want to get that same data and use it to build the entity that I'm going to store.

This is how I'm attempting to get the data

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let initialData = {};
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details').then((res) => {
        initialData = res.data;
      });
    const recruit = new RecruitModel({ email:initialData.email,
                                        mobile_number:initialData.mobile_number,
                                         name:initialData.name});
    try {
        await recruit.save()
        res.send("inserted data")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

I'm pretty sure something wrong there and nowhere else. Because if I pass static information instead it's correctly stored, no issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228143/accessing-variables-inside-a-javascript-promise-chain

Comment: @ISAE This isn't relevant to my question. My object isn't undefined.

Comment: But the properties are. Because res.data is only defined inside the promise, and you are trying to access it outside. see [how to use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises)

Comment: @ISAE Thanks I got it to work now. If you give those references in an answer I could accept it. Thanks a lot, now I have a better understanding of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving to the database's `Recruit` Collection before the promise is resolved. Since data to save in the `Recruit` Collection is dependent upon the result from the API which will initially return the promise, therefore, use promise resolving functions to wait for its result.

Solution#1 (using .then function):

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let initialData = {};

  try {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details').then((response) => {
      initialData = response.data;

      const recruit = new RecruitModel({
        email: initialData.email,
        mobile_number: initialData.mobile_number,
        name: initialData.name,
      });

      recruit.save().then((response) => res.send('inserted data'));
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Solution#2 (using async await keywords):

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details');
    const recruit = new RecruitModel({
      email: response.data.email,
      mobile_number: response.data.mobile_number,
      name: response.data.name,
    });

    await recruit.save();

    res.send('inserted data');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Either solution will work in your case.

Comment: I already used the second approach but I'll accept your answer giving that @ISAE didn't post anything

Comment: Didn't the second solution work?

Comment: It did, @ISAE provided links for how to use promises and I ended up using the second approach, it made more sense to my mind. But he never posted an answer so I'm accepting yours.